# Issue with learning C scanf function when program is run (no errors during compile) C programming absolute beginners guide Chapter 8

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I typed the following code verbatim from the book:

```
// Ex program #2 from Ch 8 of ABGTC
// File Ch8Ex2.c

// This is a sample program that asks users for some basic data and prints it on screen in order to show what was entered

#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    float cost;
    char topping[24];
    int slices;
    int month, day, year;

    // The first scanf will look for a floating-point variable, the cost of a pizza
    // If the user doesn't enter a $ before the cost, it could cause problems

    printf("How much does a pizza cost in your area? Enter as $XX.XX\n");
    scanf(" $%f", &cost);

    // The pizza topping is a string, so your scanf doesn't need an &

    printf("What is your favorite one-word pizza topping?\n");
    scanf(" %s", topping);

    printf("How many slices of %s pizza can you eat in one sitting?", topping);
    scanf(" %d", &slices);

    printf("What is today\'s date (enter it in XX/XX/XX format).\n");
    scanf(" %d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);

    printf("\n\nWhy not treat yourself to a dinner on %d/%d/%d", month, day, year);
    printf("\nand have %d slices of %s pizza!\n", slices, topping);
    printf("It will only cost you $%.2f!\n\n\n", cost);

    return 0;
}
```

Zero errors arise when I compile (Using Code:Blocks, as recommended and used in the book); yet, once I run the program, after entering the first bit of user data requested (price of a slice of pizza, let's say I said it would be 03.45), the program prints out:

```
"What is your favorite one-word pizza topping?"
"How many slices of 03.45 pizza can you eat in one sitting?"
```

It feels like it is skipping the scanf line following the printf "What is your favorite...." and not only prompting the following printf line of "How many slices....", but inserting the 03.45 as the character array/string value that should have been entered by the user in the previous line.

I've tried a few different tweaks that have come to mind, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what I've done wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the source you show really the code that is running? If you see the output it's not corresponding to what the code should do (printing the price as a string?). What is the *full* output of the program? What is the *actual* input to the program?

Comment: The source code I show is really the code that is running. I can tell that it's not corresponding.

Here is what happens when I run the program:

    "How much does pizza cost in your area?"
This is the first question, I type in 03.45 and press enter. I am then met with the following on my screen:
    "What is your favorite one-word pizza topping?"
    "How many slices of 03.45 pizza can you eat in one sitting?"
Does that elaborate a bit further?

Comment: You were missing a leading '$'. You must input something like this: `$03.45`, as the question is asking (Enter as $XX.XX)

Comment: ^ This was the whole issue.....oh my gosh hahahah thank you Amadeus!

Comment: @GuyWantingBoat: can you please accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't using $ while inputting my response. When answering the first question of "How much does a pizza cost in your area? Enter as $XX.XX", I was responding 03.45, when I should have been responding $03.45 due to the scanf being $%f. Removing the $ from "$%f" and leaving the rest the same still yields the result desired in the final print functions.

Hopefully this helps somebody else using this book!

Answer (score 1):

You do not check the return value of `scanf()`.  `scanf()` returns the number of inputs correctly parsed and stored.

In case of failure, such as not matching a missing `$` for format string `" $%f"`, the offending input stays in standard input and will be read by the next call to `scanf()` or any other input function.

You can correct the program by reading input with `fgets()` and then parsing it with `sscanf()` until a correct conversion is performed or end of file is reached.

Note that you should protect the format `%s` to prevent buffer overflow: pass the maximum number of characters to read as `scanf(" %23s", topping);`

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[80];
    float cost;
    char topping[24];
    int slices;
    int month, day, year;

    for (;;) {
        printf("How much does a pizza cost in your area? Enter as $XX.XX\n");
        if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
            return 1;
        if (sscanf(line, "$%f", &cost) == 1)
            break;
        printf("invalid input\n");
    }

    for (;;) {
        printf("What is your favorite one-word pizza topping?\n");
        if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
            return 1;
        if (sscanf(line, "%23s", topping) == 1)
            break;
        printf("invalid input\n");
    }

    for (;;) {
        printf("How many slices of %s pizza can you eat in one sitting?\n", topping);
        if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
            return 1;
        if (sscanf(line, "%d", &slices) == 1)
            break;
        printf("invalid input\n");
    }

    for (;;) {
        printf("What is today\'s date (enter it in XX/XX/XX format).\n");
        if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
            return 1;
        if (sscanf(line, "%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year) == 3)
            break;
        printf("invalid input\n");
    }

    printf("\n\nWhy not treat yourself to a dinner on %d/%d/%d\n",
           month, day, year);
    printf("and have %d slices of %s pizza!\n", slices, topping);
    printf("It will only cost you $%.2f!\n\n\n", cost);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You are missing to `flush` the standard input after taking float variable as input.

Just use the following code given below and it will solve your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    float cost;
    char topping[24];
    int slices;
    int month, day, year;

    printf("How much does a pizza cost in your area? Enter as $XX.XX\n");
    scanf(" $%f", &cost);

    fflush(stdin);    //Just add this line here and your problem is solved.

    printf("What is your favorite one-word pizza topping?\n");
    scanf(" %s", topping);

    printf("How many slices of %s pizza can you eat in one sitting?\n", topping);
    scanf(" %d", &slices);

    printf("What is today\'s date (enter it in XX/XX/XX format).\n");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);

    printf("\n\nWhy not treat yourself to a dinner on %d/%d/%d", month, day, year);
    printf("\nand have %d slices of %s pizza!\n", slices, topping);
    printf("It will only cost you $%.2f!\n\n\n", cost);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it may work but flushing the input stream with `fflush()` is still undefined behaviour in both Posix and C. But you can flush the output stream. I don't know why all of the books use `scanf()` as examples, `scanf()` is a real pain in the behind even if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Okay, so this solved the issue I had before, but now when the program goes to print the cost of the pizza (final printf function), it is saying it will cost $0.00 where it should say what the user input was (for example 03.45).

Also, since I am learning C. What does fflush(stdin) mean? What does it do?

Comment: @GuyWantingBoat The program is working fine with me. It is printing `$03.45` if the user input was 03.45

Comment: @VastalSura Amadeus solved it in a comment to the question above. It was more of an issue with user error, but removing the $ from "$%f" basically avoids the error entirely.

Comment: @GuyWantingBoat About `fflush(stdin);`  
As for fflush(stdin), the reason people call it is that some functions, scanf in particular, sometimes leave the input in a counter-intuitive state.  
For instance, say you call scanf("%d", &n) and then fgets(buf, 100, stdin), expecting an input of the form:  
10  
line  
Well it turns out that what you will get is an empty line on the fgets because scanf didn't move you past the '\n' after it read the 10.  
Because of that kind of problem, people use fflush(stdin).  
Continued...

Comment: @GuyWantingBoat  
 This is because at the time you call it, the '\n' following "10" is in the buffer but not the string "line\n".

Comment: @VatsalSura ahhhh, this makes sense. While trying to figure this out, I was wondering if there was a function that would do pretty much this, so thank you for showing it to me!

Comment: @GuyWantingBoat Please approve my answer.